# Список+таблица+js

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пжл!
Есть статический список. Нужно с помощью js по очереди каждый элемент списка занести в ячейку таблицы.

```
<script>
function addRow(){

        var field1= document.getElementById('sul')
        var field2= document.getElementById('sul')
        var field3= document.getElementById('sul')

        var tbody = document.getElementById("table").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
        var row = document.createElement("tr")
        var data1 = document.createElement("td")
        data1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(field1))
        var data2 = document.createElement("td")
        data2.appendChild (document.createTextNode(field2))
        var data3 = document.createElement("td")
        data3.appendChild (document.createTextNode(field3))
        var data4 = document.createElement("td")

        row.appendChild(data1);
        row.appendChild(data2);
        row.appendChild(data3);

        tbody.appendChild(row);
    }

</script>

</head>

<body>
<ul id="sul" value="gg">
   <li> поле1 </li>
   <li> поле2 </li>
   <li> поле3 </li>
</ul>
<table id="table" cellspacing="2" border="1"  bgcolor="#00CCFF">
    <tbody >
    <tr><td class="thd"">Поле№1</td><td class="thd" ">Поле№2</td><td class="thd" ">Поле№3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" onclick ="addRow()" value="Занести данные"  >

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Код списка покажите.

Comment: что вы хотели этим сказать ?

        var field1= document.getElementById('sul')
        var field2= document.getElementById('sul')
        var field3= document.getElementById('sul')

это примерно то-же самое что

      var result1=2*2;
      var result2=2*2;
      var result3=2*2;

Answer (score 1):

как-то так можно сделать

```
function addRow() {
    //дочерние элементы элемента с id="sul"
    var fields = document.getElementById('sul').children;
    //первый дочерний элемент элемента с id="table";
    var tbody = document.getElementById('table').children[0];
    //сделать элемент tr
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    //пройти по всем элементам из списка fields
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        //взять содержимое текущего элемента
        var data = fields[i].innerHTML;
        //сделать элемент td
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        //положить содержимое в новый td
        td.innerHTML = data;
        //добавить td в tr
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    //добавить tr в tbody
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
```

[Демо](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/qDgDY/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#sul li').each(function(){

    $('table#table').append('<tr><td>' + $(this).text() + '</td></tr>');

})
```

Comment: Юзай jquery и радуйся жизни